# OAuth access token and page refreshes

Tags: ajax, html, security, session, oauth

I can see OAuth working well for a fully Ajaxified application, as the local JS code can always replay the Bearer token to the server. However, what happens if we have a page refresh?  In that case I assume we lose the token and then go back through the OAuth redirect process to get yet a new access token issued. Is this correct, and are there patterns to avoid this, such as storing the access token in HTML5 local storage?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking OAuth 2.0 then you can probably request both [a refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) and access (or Bearer) token when you authenticate with the OAuth 2.0 provider.   The refresh token should be returned directly to the server hosting the web application, stored somehow (perhaps session state) and NOT ever exposed to the browser.   The browser can use the access token to make requests to secured services/endpoints which require it but it should have a short lifetime (regardless of whether or not there was a page refresh).   When it expires (again may or may not be due to a page refresh) the client application can make a request to the hosting server where the refresh token was delivered.  The server can then use the refresh token to get a new access token WITHOUT the user needing to login again.

There's a diagram of this in the [refresh token section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) of the OAuth 2.0 spec.

There are several variations of how OAuth 2.0 can be used and details may vary with your particular scenario and implementation but hopefully that gives you a high-level idea of how you can avoid prompting the user to re-authenticate when the access token expires or on page reload.