# Why is the my oauth page refreshing instead of authorizing the user?

Tags: heroku, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I am using [jekyll-google-auth](https://github.com/apcj/jekyll-google-auth) to secure [this website](https://github.com/FractalHardware/dashboard). Visiting the site should prompt the user to authenticate with google, and if they are in my company domain, they should get access to the site.

I have the google app set up, my dyno is up and running, but when I visit the site and click "allow" (or "deny" for that matter) I am not redirected to the site, instead it seems to refresh to the same auth page. I can click "allow" or "deny" indefinitely and never get to the site.

My redirect uri in my google app settings is:
`http://dash.fractalhardware.com/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

The command `jekyll-auth new` is supposed to run through setup for you, but it failed for me. It spit out an error when I entered my domain when prompted for GOOGLE_EMAIL_DOMAIN. So I went into the heroku settings and just added it manually in the config variables. I read through the code for the jekyll-auth command and confirmed the setup should've been complete. I don't think that's related to the auth problem but it's the only obvious hiccup I've come across.

Any idea why the oauth page seems to refresh/redirect to itself instead of authorizing the user and showing the site?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: What is the error? Have you checked on this related [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264224/oauth-access-token-and-page-refreshes)?

Comment: check in firebug if its really refreshing same site, or maybe it get back to your code, doesnt recognize that you logged in and send back again to auth page